# Trying to match a regular expression

Tags: regex, batch-file

So I'm trying to match a string in a batch script:

```
@echo off
%reg% = ^[a-Z]|6[0-9]
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%v IN (`powershell -noprofile "& { (get-date).ToString('MMddyy') }"`) DO set "d=%%v"
echo %d%

START "" "C:\Program Files\SEAGULL\BlueZone\BZFTP.EXE" /Fccaihfs.zft /CWD"/u/aidrev/aidoccai/outbound PAUSE /L"TYPE A" /L"RETR AIDOCCAI.D[%d%].T042456.MO.EDIPROD"
```

In the script I call powershell to get me a formatted date

I am trying to call up an FTP program called bluezone FTP. They have initial command list that start with /L

`/L"RETR AIDOCCAI.D[%d%].T042456.MO.EDIPROD"`
This string RETR (retrieves) a file.

The AIDOCCAI is standard and maybe should be matched? What do you guys think?

The T042456 part is what I'd like to match.
So it would be like:

`/L"RETR AIDOCCAI.D[%d%].[%reg%].MO.EDIPROD"`

This is what I got
`%reg% = ^[a-Z]|6[0-9]}`

Will this match this type of string? I probably also need to escape it, is that correct? I also believe the string always starts with T

`AIDOCCAI.D[%d%].T042456.MO.EDIPROD"`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm using batch.

Comment: Why downvote? I attempted to answer it, and did research?

Comment: I use this site. It helps in regex's : http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php. According to the site that would actually be wrong. It spits out : `/[a-zA-Z]\d{6}/`

Comment: nice tool @ThePlatypus thanks!

Comment: here let me edit question, these downvotes are unnecessary.

Comment: and why vote to close? I'm trying to learn regex you rude tech dude!

Comment: @Hituptony The downvotes are based around the way in which the question is being asked within the guidelines for SO, they are not aimed at the ability of the person asking the question (we all started somewhere).

Comment: `%reg% = ^[a-Z]|6[0-9]` is meaningless to batch. If you want to `set` a variable to a string, you need `set "var=value"` (the quotes prevent unwanted inclusion of spaces) - the spaces are significant on both sides of the `=`. Even then, the code you've posted doesn't include any use of the value you appear to want to assign to `reg`. Sorry - no idea of what you want. English preferred, and minimise the shorthand.

Comment: @Magoo I updated to where I would put the variable. Thanks for the quote and space comment. Very helpful

Comment: @JakeGould ummm...ya. It's not a duplicate I ask how to implement FINDSTR not find the REg ex pattern?

Comment: WHY NOT JUST CLOSE THIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an alphabetical character (you say "alphanumeric", but I suspect that was an error in the question) followed by 6 integers, the regular expression would be:

```
[A-Za-z]\d{6}
```

Comment: will this escape the string as well?

Comment: @Hituptony I'm unsure what you're referring to; can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: check updated question sorry it was a bit vague

Comment: @Hituptony You've actually managed to make it significantly more complex ... and, made my answer look pointless as you've incorporated it back into the question!